# Не происходит переход на следующий слайд

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var slide_left = document.getElementById('slide-left'),
  slide_right = document.getElementById('slide-right'),
  total_slide = document.getElementsById('slide'),
  idx = 0; // Индекс текущего слайда.

slide_right.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
  slide_left.style.display = 'block';
  total_slide[idx].style.display = 'none'; // Скрываем текущий слайд
  total_slide[++idx].style.display = 'block'; // Инкрементируем индекс и показываем следующий слайд
  if (idx === total_slide.length - 1) { // Убираем "правую" стрелку, если справа слайдов больше нет
    slide_right.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//Аналогично, только для левой стрелки
slide_left.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  slide_right.style.display = 'block';
  total_slide[idx].style.display = 'none';
  total_slide[--idx].style.display = 'block';
  if (idx === 0) {
    slide_left.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap-slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider form {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}

.slider-nav .slider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #F62459;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-nav .slider-left {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

.slider-nav .slider-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap-slider">
    <form action="" method="post" class="slider">
      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 1</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 2</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 3</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Конец</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер"></p>
        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваше мыло"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div id="slide-left" class="slider-arrow slider-left">&#8592;</div>
      <div id="slide-right" class="slider-arrow slider-right">&#8594;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ID уникальный идентификатор он не может повторятсья у вас ID повторяетсья 500 раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут `id` уникален, два одинаковых `id` не может быть:

```
<div class="slider" id="slide">
```

Метода `getElementsById` не существует:

```
total_slide = document.getElementsById('slide');
```

Поскольку `id` уникален, нужно использовать `class`. Что бы получить массив элементов по определенному классу нужно воспользоваться методом `querySelectorAll`.

Пример:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
```

Ваш пример:

```js
var formSlider = document.querySelector('#form-slider'),
    divSlideArray = formSlider.querySelectorAll('.slide');

var divSliderArrows = document.querySelector('#slider-arrows'),
    divArrowLeft = divSliderArrows.querySelector('.arrow-left'),
    divArrowRight = divSliderArrows.querySelector('.arrow-right');

var currentSlide = 0;

divArrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide > 0) {
        divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[--currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == 0)
            divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }
});

divArrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (currentSlide < divSlideArray.length - 1) {
        divArrowLeft.style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
        divSlideArray[++currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

        if (currentSlide == divSlideArray.length - 1)
            divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    }

});
```

```css
#wrapper .wrap-slider {
    position: relative;
}

#form-slider {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
}

#form-slider .slide {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#form-slider .slide:first-child ~ .slide {
    display: none;
}

#slider-arrows [class^="arrow"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    color: #F62459;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-left {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-right {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="wrap-slider">
        <form id="form-slider" action="" method="post">
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Вопрос 1</p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer1"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer2"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer3"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <p>Вопрос 2</p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <p>Вопрос 3</p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer1"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer2"></p>
                <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer3"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <p>Конец</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер"></p>
                <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваше мыло"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="slider-arrows">
            <div class="arrow-left">&#8592;</div>
            <div class="arrow-right">&#8594;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нормально скопипастил.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя не работает строчка:

```
total_slide = document.getElementsById('slide')
```

Используй `querySelectorAll`:

```js
var slide_left = document.getElementById('slide-left'),
  slide_right = document.getElementById('slide-right'),
  total_slide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide'),
  idx = 0; // Индекс текущего слайда.

slide_right.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
  slide_left.style.display = 'block';
  total_slide[idx].style.display = 'none'; // Скрываем текущий слайд
  total_slide[++idx].style.display = 'block'; // Инкрементируем индекс и показываем следующий слайд
  if (idx === total_slide.length - 1) { // Убираем "правую" стрелку, если справа слайдов больше нет
    slide_right.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//Аналогично, только для левой стрелки
slide_left.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  slide_right.style.display = 'block';
  total_slide[idx].style.display = 'none';
  total_slide[--idx].style.display = 'block';
  if (idx === 0) {
    slide_left.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap-slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider form {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}

.slider-nav .slider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #F62459;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-nav .slider-left {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

.slider-nav .slider-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap-slider">
    <form action="" method="post" class="slider">
      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 1</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 2</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Вопрос 3</p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer1"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer2"></p>
        <p>Ответ <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="answer3"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="slider" id="slide">
        <p>Конец</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер"></p>
        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите Ваше мыло"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div id="slide-left" class="slider-arrow slider-left">&#8592;</div>
      <div id="slide-right" class="slider-arrow slider-right">&#8594;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```